# Flutter API Post request is fetching wrong response first time

Tags: flutter, dart, request, http-post, httpresponse

I'm facing a bizarre issue while making a post request from flutter. I've a list of object being returned in the HTTP Post response, but the response is not as expected at first, but while making the second request, I'm getting the correct output.

Note:

1. I'm getting the default false values for all boolean attributes of the object at first time response
2. I'm getting the correct response through swagger and postman at first time, facing the issue through flutter.

Response at first time:

> [{"param1":"","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4","param5":false},
> {"param1":"","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4","param5":false}]

Response at second time (boolean value is different during second request):

> [{"param1":"","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4","param5":true},
> {"param1":"","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4","param5":true}]

I'm using `http.dart` for making the post request.

I've tried the following ways

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse("url?param=" + param),    
);
```

and this one...

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse("url?param=" + param),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: null,
);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: and what do you see if you `print(response.body)` for the first time?

Comment: First time: [{"param1":"","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4","param5":false},
{"param1":"","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4","param5":false}]

second time: 
[{"param1":"","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4","param5":true},
{"param1":"","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4","param5":true}]